# std::setw() is not giving desired results

Tags: c++, c++11, codeblocks

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr; i++)
{
    cout << left << setw(25);
    cout << names[i] << " " << age[i];
    cout << setw(25);
    cout << fname[i] << endl;
}
```

Here the arrays `names`,`age` and `fname` contain name, age and father's name, respectively.

Output of my code is:

```
zeel dev                 18r k sanghai
amar singh               25r k sanghai
alex pandit              52s n vardhan
```

After the `age`column, I want a gap of another 25 columns. How can I do that?
`setw()` is not working properly.

Comment: you put `setw(25)` before `name` because you want name `25` wide, now you want `age` to be `25` wide, but you didnt put `setw` before `age`. Voting to close as typo

Comment: Not clear. Are you wanting three left-aligned columns?

Comment: `setw` affects the *next* value that gets printed, then the stream resets its width back to normal. The value is printed *inside* the width you setup. So, if you want 3 columns of fixed width, you have to use `setw` 3 times per line. But you are using it only 2 times. You are not specifying a width for the `age` column.